# Save large audio as w64 in python

Tags: python, numpy, audio, wav, librosa

I have a directory of 10,000 wav files, each 30 seconds long. The total duration is about 83 hours. I read them into python like this:

```
import os
import librosa
import numpy as np

x = np.array([librosa.load(f, sr=16000)[0] for f i sorted(os.listdir(root))])
```

My understanding is that, to save the audio, I must use `w64` given the duration limitations of `wav`. I have plenty of ram and storage.

How do I save `x` in `w64` format in python?

Comment: Conservatively that’s about 9GB of data. It might not be a good deal to load that all in one go.

Comment: Can you provide a reason why you would want to create such a large wave file?

Comment: For my experiment, I have a transmitter and a receiver. I want to play the audio, transmit it, and record the audio at the receiver. This gives me realistic transmission noise.

Comment: I want to let the audio for the experiment run without having to check on it often.